# отправка почты с мета тегами

Tags: email, sendmail, метаданные

доброго времени суток, интересует возможность отправки писем с произвольными незименяемыми мета-данными. ситуация: система обработки заявок(СОЗ), клиенту отправляется письмо, в теме идентификатор заявки, который редактируется, поменяв его СОЗ не сможет понять к какой заявке пришёл ответ. поиск мне не помог. есть ли технически такая возможность - закреплять за сообщением какие то данные, которые бы использовались при ответах?

Comment: Генерировать индивидуальные адреса отправки каждому письму.

Comment: чёт как то перебор, проще вариантов нет?

Comment: Почему перебор? Если у вас почтовый домен свой, то все пришедшие письма можно в один ящик кидать. Еще можно как на gmail: myemail+pumpum@gmail.com - письма падают в ящик myemail@gmail.com.

Comment: Если я правильно понял проблему можно попробовать использовать in reply to - уникальный id письма на которое ответ